# Linking to libcrypto for Leopard?

Tags: cocoa, macos, openssl, aquaticprime

I am using Mac OS X 10.6 SDK and my deployment target is set to Mac OS 10.5.  I'm linking to libcrypto (AquaticPrime requires this) and found out that my app doesn't launch on Leopard.  The error is

`dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib`

I've tried the following workarounds but none of them work:

- Linking directly to `libcrypto.0.9.7.dylib` (the 10.6 SDK refuses to link directly with `libcrypto.0.9.7.dylib`.
- Copying the 10.5 SDK's version of `libcrypto.0.9.7.dylib` to the 10.6 lib directory and try t link with it (this time the link process succeeded but in Leopard the app still tries to lookup the non-existent `libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib` file and thus won't launch).
- Copying `libcrypto.0.9.7.dylib` from a Mac OS X 10.5.8 installation and link with it (the link was successful but the app still looks for `libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib`).

Is there a way to link to this library and still use the 10.6 SDK?

Thanks.

Comment: Describe how you are linking to the library. I'm using this just fine, as are others, so either something is wrong with your installation or you're linking incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try setting the base SDK to 10.5 in your target build settings.

Comment: Yes.. this one worked.  I set the base SDK to 10.5 but set the active SDK to 10.6.  This way I have 10.6 source codes (e.g. those that implement 10.6 protocols) and still able to run the app in 10.5.

Thanks.

Comment: Now that the "Active SDK" option is removed in XCode 3.2.3, what should I do for this issue?

Comment: You are a bit limited in options now.  The issue occurs because the 10.6 SDK has an version of libcrypto in it that is incompatible with the one that ships in 10.5.  By setting the base SDK to 10.5, you are saying that it is the maximum SDK version you are going to use.  Technically, you shouldn't be using 10.6 headers.

Comment: The nice thing is that now in XCode 3.2.3, I can use the 10.6 SDK and yet link to the libcrypto in 10.5 SDK.  So is the new workaround for XCode 3.2.3.

Comment: @JeremyP Are you sure this answer is still current?

Comment: The 10.7 version of libcrypto is still 0.9.8.  So it's probably still current.  However, it's possible that Xcode no longer supports 10.5.

Answer (score 22):

As per this thread here ( first post in thread: http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2009/Aug/msg01737.html , "libcrypto on Snow Leopard" thread listing: http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2009/Aug/thrd19.html ), I believe the solution is to do the following:

1. Go to /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk/usr/lib/ .  From this folder, copy "libcrypto.0.9.7.dylib" to your project source folder.
2. Rename the file you just copied to "libmycrypto.dylib".
3. Add the file you just renamed to your project.  Make sure to remove any other linked libcrypto frameworks from your project.
4. Go through your build settings, and make sure you *remove* the "-lcrypto" linker flag.  (It's usually put in the "Other Linker Flags" setting.)

Now you should be able to build your project and it will work on both 10.5 and 10.6.

(libcrypto.0.9.7 is available on both 10.5 and 10.6.  The file you copied is just a stub of the headers, but you're just linking against it, *not* embedding it in your project.  Since the linker uses the install path not the actual filename of the dylib, naming it "libmycrypto.dylib" eliminates path conflicts, but still allows you to link against the library you need.

FWIW, this is an Xcode problem.  You should be able to link against /usr/lib/libcrypto.dylib -- the symbolic link -- and have it target the correct version of libcrypto on both 10.5 and 10.6.  However, Xcode always seems to link to version 0.9.8 when building on Snow Leopard for some reason.)

Comment: Great answer, just what I was looking for. Cheers.

Comment: If you want build your app on 10.6+, but run it on 10.5, this is the answer you should use (not the one checked above.) Also: when you're looking for -lcrypto linker flags, remember that they can be in both the project level settings as well as the individual targets. Make sure you remove ALL of them.

Comment: Maybe this will work with ObjectiveC, but not with C++/gcc. Only use of 10.5 SDK via -isysroot option worked to link against 0.9.7 versions of libssl/libcrypto - you need not only to LINK against those dylibs, but COMPILE using their H files of 0.9.7. Also when building on 10.7/10.8 using 10.5 SDK, deep in STL headers of 10.5 SDK, there are symlinks like i686-apple-darwin10 pointing to i686-apple-darwin9. You need to create such symlinks for darwin11 and darwin12 (for both i686 and x86_64). To be precise, directory with those symlinks is /MacOSX10.5.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you're using the lib for, you might be able to replace libcrypto with CommonCrypto which works well with both 10.5 and 10.6. I've used libcrypto only for the MD5 function, so I replaced openssl/md5.h with CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h and MD5() with CC_MD5(), and libcrypto with CommonCrypto, and now it works on both Leopards.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried linking against libcrypto.0.9.dylib or libcrypto.dylib instead of the specific versions?

Comment: Yes.
- linking to `libcrypto.0.9.dylib` causes linker errors
- linking to `libcrypto.dylib` links and builds just fine but the app fails to launch in Leopard.

Answer (score 0):

Leopard OS X ships with a libcrypto and libssl that only has the ppc architecture.

A simple solution that doesn't require changing the code of the app is to backup your libcrypto.0.9.dylib, libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib, libssl0.9.dylib, libssl.0.9.8.dylib and copy over the libcrypto.0.9.7.dylib and libssl.0.9.7.dylib.

You can use Terminal.app to make these changes in your Applications folder:

```
  cd /usr/lib
  sudo cp libcrypto.0.9.dylib libcrypto.0.9.dylib.old
  sudo cp libssl.0.9.dylib libssl.0.9.dylib.old
  sudo ln -sf libcrypto.0.9.7.dylib libcrypto.0.9.dylib
  sudo ln -sf libssl.0.9.7.dylib libssl.0.9.dylib
```

Here's an alternative solution that lets you stay on the freshest openssl version:

```
  1. reactivate the current openssl: port activate openssl@1.0.0c_0 (or whatever)
  2. clean up your old unwanted versions of everything: port uninstall inactive
  3. uninstall badly behaved ports: port uninstall md5sha1sum subversion neon
  4. get them back: port install subversion md5sha1sum
```