# further Linking to libcrypto for Leopard

Tags: xcode, macos, macros, osx-leopard, aquaticprime

Using XCode 3.2.5, I have recently changed my Base SDK from 10.5 to 10.6 (Deployment SDK is still 10.5) and have run into the same thing as mentioned in this thread:
[Linking to libcrypto for Leopard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2616738/linking-to-libcrypto-for-leopard)

So the correct libcrypto image is not found when loading the application under Leopard. (Used by Aquatic Prime).

My question is - is this really still the right solution 17 months later? It seems like there has been several XCode releases and OS updates since then, and previous posters have said they have filed bug reports with Apple, I'm just finding it hard to believe that a bug this big still exists. Also, I haven't found any mention of this problem in the Apple Developer Forums which is hard to believe too. It makes me think that I've set something up wrong or other people would still be running into this problem as well.

I have no problem implementing the solution outlined in the previous thread (haven't tried it yet though), I just want to make sure that I'm solving the right problem.