# Linker failing when trying to link with libcrypto

Tags: xcode, macos

I'm trying to compile an older objective C app for the mac on XCODE 4.2

I'm getting a link error when trying to compile

cannot link directly with /usr/lib/libssl.0.9.7.dylib for architecture x86_64

any idea why that is and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

After migration, you'll want to link to symlink `libcrypto.dylib` instead of the version-numbered dylib (`libcrypto.0.9.7.dylib`) if you do  not need to maintain backward compatibility. The symlink will resolve to the proper version OS X 10.6+, but not to 10.5 or previous.

If you need any `lib*.0.9*.dylib` in your program, you'll need to manually preserve those libraries and put them into your program. You can find information on this solution in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2620698/571506